# Sqlite has problems with python3 installations

Tags: python

Python3.7 always has errors under import sqlite3

Try to reproduce sqlite-autoconf-3280000 and make, make python3.7, but it will not work

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: libsqlite3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: [Skype cannot find libsqlite3.so.0](https://askubuntu.com/a/438097)